# date time from hell. separating date and time in R

Tags: r, datetime

I have a dataframe with datetime and to separate I use

```
hours = format(as.POSIXct(strptime(x,"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", tz="")) ,format = "%H:%M"))
```

separates the date and time. Unfortunately the time is in AM/PM and it doesnt comvert to 24h so 1 am and 1pm are the same. I use lubridate and get a NA and a warning "All formats failed to parse. No formats found."

```
mdy_hm(x)
```

In desperation i use

```
as.POSIXct(strptime(hourly_intensities$ActivityHour,"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", tz=""))
```

and it converts the am/pm to hh:mm:ss but only some of the data. not all.

I also tried with one number and lubridate works only if I put the value in "". what do I do to solve this?
the data looks like this :

| row | date time |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4/12/2016 12:00:00 AM |
| 2 | 4/12/2016 1:00:00 AM |
| 3 | 4/12/2016 2:00:00 AM |
| 4 | 4/12/2016 3:00:00 PM |
| 5 | 4/12/2016 4:00:00 PM |
| 6 | 4/12/2016 5:00:00 AM |
| 7 | 4/12/2016 6:00:00 AM |
| 8 | 4/12/2016 7:00:00 PM |
| 9 | 4/12/2016 8:00:00 AM |
| 10 | 4/12/2016 9:00:00 PM |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do two things:

1. Because your times are in 12-hour format, you need `%I` in your format order (rather than the usual `%H`).
2. To let `lubridate` know that it should keep track of AM/PM, you need to conclude the format order with `%p%`.

The code below should be able to parse the examples you gave above.

```
library(lubridate)

parse_date_time('4/12/2016 3:00:00 PM', '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')

> [1] "2016-04-12 15:00:00 UTC"
```

Answer (score 2):

It's all in the documentation of base R, if you know where look. In this case, `help(strptime)`.

Here is  a working example for your first two data points:

```
> strptime(c("4/12/2016 12:00:00 AM", "4/12/2016 01:00:00 AM"), "%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
[1] "2016-12-04 00:00:00 CST" "2016-12-04 01:00:00 CST"
>
```

The keys are `%I` for hours along with `%p` for the AM/PM indicator.

Answer (score 0):

Use `dmy_hms` to convert date.time to Posixct format and extract date and time component from it.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(date.time = dmy_hms(date.time), 
         date = date(date.time), 
         time = format(date.time, '%T'))

#   row           date.time       date     time
#1    1 2016-12-04 00:00:00 2016-12-04 00:00:00
#2    2 2016-12-04 01:00:00 2016-12-04 01:00:00
#3    3 2016-12-04 02:00:00 2016-12-04 02:00:00
#4    4 2016-12-04 15:00:00 2016-12-04 15:00:00
#5    5 2016-12-04 16:00:00 2016-12-04 16:00:00
#6    6 2016-12-04 05:00:00 2016-12-04 05:00:00
#7    7 2016-12-04 06:00:00 2016-12-04 06:00:00
#8    8 2016-12-04 19:00:00 2016-12-04 19:00:00
#9    9 2016-12-04 08:00:00 2016-12-04 08:00:00
#10  10 2016-12-04 21:00:00 2016-12-04 21:00:00
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(row = 1:10, date.time = c("4/12/2016 12:00:00 AM", 
"4/12/2016 1:00:00 AM", "4/12/2016 2:00:00 AM", "4/12/2016 3:00:00 PM", 
"4/12/2016 4:00:00 PM", "4/12/2016 5:00:00 AM", "4/12/2016 6:00:00 AM", 
"4/12/2016 7:00:00 PM", "4/12/2016 8:00:00 AM", "4/12/2016 9:00:00 PM"
)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.